# I want to load all the images in a folder in a google maps info window

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I am loading a bunch of markers into google maps from an xml file. Each marker's name will correspond with a folder of images on the server. When populating the information box I want to display all the images in the corresponding folder.

www.frackwatch.co.za

Everything works except the images do not display. In their place instead is [Object][Object].

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.5, 24.0),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      var info = markers[i].getAttribute("info");
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var folder = "attachments/" + name +"/";

      var html = "<b>" + info + "</b> <br/>" + $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
          $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpeg|png|gif)$/) ) {
              $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val   +"'>" );
            }
          });
        }
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icn
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

<div id="map"></div>
```

Correct code but only loads images for the first marker:

```
function load() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29, 25.0),
zoom: 6,
mapTypeId: 'satellite'
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

  var info = markers[i].getAttribute("info");
  var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
  var folder = "/attachments/" + id +"/";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icn
  });
$.ajax({
url : folder,
success: function (data) {
    var html = "<b>" + info + "</b><br/>";
    $(data).find("a").each(function () {
    $this = $(this)
    if($this.attr('href').match(/\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$/)) {
    html +=  "<img src="+ folder + $this.attr('href') + ">";
  }
});
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});  
}
});
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
  request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
  callback(request, request.status);
}
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: Please, use proper indentation in your source code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var html = "<b>" + info + "</b> <br/>" + $.ajax({url : folder,success:     function (data) {$(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {if( val.match(/\.(jpeg|png|gif)$/) ) { $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val   +"'>" );} });}});;
```

The `$.ajax` function does not return anything. Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
So the `var html = [...] + $.ajax` is broken.

You are trying to display all images in a folder in a InfoWindow ?
If so, it should something like :

```
var folder = "attachments/" + name +"/";
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icn
});

$.ajax({
  url : folder,
  success: function (data) {
    var html = "<b>" + info + "</b> <br/>";
    $(data).find("a").each(function () {
      $this = $(this)
      if($this.attr('href').match(/\.(jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        html +=  "<img src=" +  $this.attr('href') + ">";
      }
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
   }
 });
```

`bindInfoWindow` should be in the ajax callback otherwise the result can be there yet.

**A cleaner way** would be that `genxml.php` lists all images so you won't have to request the files in folder afterwards.

Comment: Yes I know that is where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Not trying to create a marker for every image.. all i want to do is display all the images in the said folder.

Comment: the code works fine, it creates markers based on an xml file and creates the infoboxes with the correct data. it just doesn't display the images in the infoboxes.

Comment: www.frackwatch.co.za

Comment: Thank you but still does not work. Where would the bindInfoWindow be place as I have it further down already.

Comment: 1 - create the marker, 2 - request the folder, 3 - inside the ajax callback : create the html by concatenation of the img, bind the InfoWindow with the proper html.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is loading the images now for the first marker but does not load any images for markers after that.. cheers.